# Loop to check apple position against snake body positions

Tags: c++, position, sfml

I'm trying to figure out how to write a loop to check the position of a circle against a variable number of rectangles so that the apple is not placed on top of the snake, but I'm having a bit of trouble thinking it through. I tried:

```
do 
   apple.setPosition(randX()*20+10, randY()*20+10); // apple is a CircleShape
while (apple.getPosition() == snakeBody[i].getPosition());
```

Although, in this case, if it detects a collision with one rectangle of the snake's body, it could end up just placing the apple at a previous position of the body. How do I make it check all positions at the same time, so it can't correct itself only to have a chance of repeating the same problem again?

Comment: Do you have a function to check overlap of circleshape and rectangle ?

Comment: Yeah, but it just checks overlap of the head of the snake and the apple, so if (snakeBody[0].getPosition() == apple.getPosition())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways (I could think of) of generating a random number meeting a requirement:

- The first way, and the simpler, is what you're trying to do: retry if it doesn't.
  However, you should change the condition so that it checks all the forbidden cells at once:

  ```
  bool collides_with_snake(const sf::Vector2f& pos, //not sure if it's 2i or 2f
                           const /*type of snakeBody*/& snakeBody,
                           std::size_t partsNumber) {
    bool noCollision = true;
    for( std::size_t i = 0 ; i < partsNumber && noCollision ; ++i )
      noCollision = pos != snakeBody[i].getPosition()
    return !noCollision;
  }

  //...
  do 
    apple.setPosition(randX()*20+10, randY()*20+10);
  while (collides_with_snake(apple.getCollision(), snakeBody,
                             /* snakeBody.size() ? */));
  ```
- The second way is to try to generate less numbers and find a function which will map these numbers to the set you want. For instance, if your grid has `N` cells, you could generate a number between `0` and `N - [number of parts of your Snake]` then map this number `X` to the smallest number `Y` such that this integer doesn't refer to a cell occupied by a snake part and `X = Y + S` where `S` is the number of cells occupied by a snake part referred by a number smaller than `Y`.
  It's more complicated though.
- The third way is to *"cheat"* and choose a stronger requirement which is easier to enforce. For instance, if you know that the cell body is `N` cells long, then only spawn the apple on a cell which is `N + 1` cells away of the snakes head (you can do that by generating the angle).

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad,  but assuming that `snakeBody` is a vector of `Rectangles` (or derived from Rectanges), and that you have a `checkoverlap()` function:

```
do {
   // assuming that randX() and randY() allways return different random variables
   apple.setPosition(randX()*20+10, randY()*20+10); // set the apple
  } while (any_of(snakeBody.begin(), snakeBody.end(), [&](Rectangle &r)->bool { return checkoverlap(r,apple); } );
```

This relies on standard algorithm **[`any_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/any_of/)** to check in one simple expression if any of the snake body elements overlaps the apple.  If there's an overlap, we just iterate once more and get a new random position until it's fine.

If snakebody is an array and not a standard container, just use `snakeBody, snakeBody+snakesize` instead of `snakeBody.begin(), snakeBody.end()` in the code above.

If the overlap check is as simple as to compare the postition you can replace `return checkoverlap(r,apple);` in the code above with `return r.getPosition()==apple.getPosition();`

Answer (score 0):

The "naive" approach would be generating apples and testing their positions against the whole snake until we find a free spot:

```
bool applePlaced = false;
while(!applePlaced) { //As long as we haven't found a valid place for the apple
    apple.setPosition(randX()*20+10, randY()*20+10);
    applePlaced = true;  //We assume, that we can place the apple
    for(int i=0; i<snakeBody.length; i++) { //Check the apple position with all snake body parts
        if(apple.getPosition() == snakeBody[i].getPosition()) {
            applePlaced=false;  //Our prediction was wrong, we could not place the apple
            break; //No further testing necessary
        }
    }
}
```

The better way would be storing all free positions in an array and then pick a Position out of this array(and delete it from the array), so that no random testing is necessary. It requires also updating the array if the snakes moves.